# JavaScript functions referenced from external JS file using a <script> tag are reporting as "not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nginx

**EDIT:** See my answer below, since this works now :)

Fair warning, I've only been coding in JavaScript/JQuery for a couple months now, and I feel this is just something simple I haven't picked up on yet.  There are quite a few similar questions around SO, and the web, but none of the answers I'm finding seem to be working for me.

I'm referencing a few external JS files in the `<head>` element of my html file...

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="javascript" src="globalVars.js"></script>
  <script type="javascript" src="gatherInfo.js"></script>
</head>
```

The variables I have stored in globalVars.js, are working fine.  I can access them with no problem.  However, the functions I have stored in gatherInfo.js are showing up as `Uncaught ReferenceError: functionName is not defined` in the console of the browser (both Chrome and Firefox).

The gatherInfo.js file is just a bucket of functions I'm using to gather/parse data from a server.  For example, here's the very first function in the gatherInfo.js file...

```
var getAuthInfo = function() {
  authInfo = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/auth',
    data: {"type": "normal", "username": loginName, "password": loginPassword},
    success: setAuthToken,
    error: authFail,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true
  });
};
```

If I move the functions from the gatherInfo.js file, and put them directly into the html file, in the `<body>` element, within a `<script>` element, they work fine.

I'm willing to post everything I've tried, but that would turn this into quite a lengthy question... so let me know if any other info would be helpful.

**EDIT:** @Derek This gets confusing, so bear with me... I feel I'm missing something here.

Here are my file sizes for my external JS files;
`gatherInfo.js = 4.4KB`
`globalVars.js = 611B`

Now, here's what I see in the network tab on Chrome Dev Tools on each load attempt.
(Note: I'm loading the page with "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" on each attempt)

With my src attributes set like so `src="/globalVars.js"` and `src="/gatherInfo.js"`...
The network tab shows the files being fetched, but the size of each file being fetched is 1.5KB, which doesn't match of course.

Now, with my src attributes set without leading `/`, like so `src="globalVars.js"` and `src="gatherInfo.js"`...
The globalVars.js file being fetched is 912B, and the gatherInfo.js file being fetched is 4.7KB.
Assuming the slightly larger file size is just packet overhead,
it looks like it's now at least fetching the correct files. The function calls are still reporting as `not defined` though.

Here's where I start getting really confused...
If I change my src attribute to something nonsensical/nonexistent, like so `src="/dub/mud/fub/globalVars.js"`...
It still shows that it's successfully fetching the files, but they're back to 1.5KB in size... so clearly not the correct file. But it doesn't return a 404 not found.

And to go one step further, if I set the src attribute to a filename that just doesn't exist `src="fubar.js"`...
It will kick back a 404 not found error.

I have no idea why it's acting like it's fetching globalVars.js and gatherInfo.js, even when I give it a completely incorrect path, but it'll kick back a 404 on a nonexistent file.

**EDIT:**  I went ahead and setup a gist with all 3 files in their entirety.

https://gist.github.com/Eschin/317dc67a50a1297393d0

As you can see, in overview.html, where I have all the JS functions commented out in the body... if I uncomment those, they work fine.  They break when moved to the gatherInfo.js file, and are referenced via the script tag.

Comment: Do you see other errors in the console when the page loads? When JavaScript encounters a syntax error (or some other error) while processing a `<script>` file, it'll abort the whole process, leaving functions declared after the error undefined.

Comment: Can you show a `script` block that's *calling* one of the missing functions?  And you don't have anything like `<script>` tags *in* `gatherInfo.js`, right?

Comment: what's your folder structure look like?

Comment: @Pointy The only error I initially see upon loading the page is `Uncaught ReferenceError: formChange is not defined`.  This function is also stored in gatherInfo.js.  Other `Uncaught ReferenceError` will show up if I interact with the page, all of them referring to methods inside the gatherInfo.js file.  formChange is a function that my login form calls from within the `<body>` element of my html file.

Comment: @Paul Roub I don't have any script tags inside the gatherInfo.js file.  In fact, `var getAuthInfo = function() {` is line 1 of the gatherInfo.js file, and all that follows are subsequent function declarations.  Here's a line from my login form that calls one of the functions `<input type="text" name="loginName" onkeyup="formChange()" onchange="formChange()">`.  The formChange function call is the initial `Uncaught ReferenceError` that shows up in the browser console after loading the page.

Comment: @Derek There is no folder structure yet, there's only a few files, all in the same directory/folder.

Comment: when you load the page, look up your `Network` tab in developer tools window. does the `/gatherInfo.js` actually get fetched?

Comment: There isn't enough information provided to make a solid call, but you are binding an anonymous function to a variable, so the function has no name. Use `function getAuthInfo() { ... }`

Comment: @MichaelClaramunt if the JS files are in the same directory, remove the `/` from the front of the file name

Comment: @MohMah Yes, according to the network tab, it's being successfully fetched in 6ms.

Comment: @Tomanow My fledgling understanding of JavaScript, is that `var functionName = function() { /* code */ };` is the proper way to store and name a function, whereas an anonymous function is a function created and immediately executed, without saving to a variable...?  Maybe I'm wrong.  The functions work fine when called with the variable name when moved to the HTML file.  I'll try renaming them today with your suggested syntax, and report back.  Maybe I'm wrong with the way I'm saving the functions to the variable names.

Comment: @MichaelClaramunt check out [Function Statements vs. Function Expressions](http://www.unicodegirl.com/function-statement-versus-function-expression.html) ;)

Comment: @Derek I updated my original question based on your suggestion to remove the leading `/` from my src attribute.

Comment: @Tomanow Good read; I tried changing the syntax to `function formChange( ) { /* code */ };`.  

As well as `function formChangeFunc( ) { /* code */ };` then saving that to a variable `var formChange = formChangeFunc( );`

Both ways still report formChange being undefined.  Wondering if I'm still missing something, as the functions work fine when declared as `var formChange = function() { /* code */ };` within the HTML file itself... They only break when I move them to a different file, and reference them with a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out what was causing the issue... turned out to be an NGINX problem.

Quoted from http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/external/2.html, in order to use external JS files...*Your Web server must be set up to map the ".js" file extension to the MIME type "text/javascript."*

I noticed by clicking on the file name in the Network tab of the dev tools, that the server was actually returning `Content-Type: application/x-javascript`.

Also, seeing elsewhere that `application\javascript` was the most current MIME-type to use, I made this change...

Editing the `/etc/nginx/mime.types` file on the server, and changing `application/x-javascript js;` to `application/javascript js;` fixed the problem.  All external files getting fetched are returning as `Content-Type: application/javascript` now, and they're working :)

Looks like I have some reading to do, as I've always just ignored MIME-type... not even really sure what it is, exactly... But problem fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I am only guessing at the issue you're having, but if your functions are wrapped in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), using `var` would not make those variables global.

I think the best idea would be to add a global namespace for your code. Each file should have the following template code:

```
(function(){

  if ( !window.myNamespace ) {
    window.myNamespace = {};
  } 

  myNamespace.function01 = function(){ /* add code here */ };
  myNamespace.function02 = function(){ /* add code here */ };

})();
```

In your case, use `getAuthInfo` instead of `function01`, etc... and then when you call a function, make sure to include that namespacing. For example:

```
myNamespace.getAuthInfo();
```

Comment: Is that all there is to namespacing? I thought there would be more involved, I'm going to give it try.

Comment: @Mottie Not sure if this applies, as my functions aren't wrapped inside an IIFE (Unless I'm ignorant to what that means exactly.)

I went ahead and setup a secret gist on github with all 3 files in their entirety .

https://gist.github.com/Eschin/317dc67a50a1297393d0

I'll try your suggestion sometime soon, and report back with the results